# Python "with open" statement creates file with directory as name, but not in the actual directory

Tags: python, python-3.7

I want to save JSON-data to a (before not existing) file using the following code, which works with Python 3.6.5:

```
with open("Samples\\{}.json".format(id), "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    json.dump(labels, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

This will create a new .json file in the folder Samples.
Now I tried the same with Python 3.7.3, but instead of creating a new .json file in said directory, it creates a file with a name like "Samples\xyz.json" in the directory the python code is running (running in a jupyter notebook).

I tried the following already, but it results in the same problem creating a file with the directory as file name:

```
f = open(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("Samples/{}.json".format(document_id)))
json.dump(labels, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

How can I create a new .json file in the desired directory with Python 3.7.3?

Comment: you are using `join` incorrectly.. it should be join('Examples', '{}.json'.format(doc))

Comment: @johnashu I get an error "[Errno 2] No such file or directory" since the .json doesn't exist before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with pathlib & f-string:

```
from pathlib import Path
document_id = 100 # Random id here ...
sample_file = Path("Samples") / f"{document_id}.json"
sample_file.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
with sample_file.open("w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    json.dump(labels, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```